# If an equation describes some physical phenomenon is the assumption that it works in all cases?

Tags: dirac-equation, antimatter, models

I may be misunderstanding the general idea and the following specific example, but I was told that Dirac predicted the existence of the positron based on a formula for the motion of the electron(?) and then feeding in a negative value or imaginary value and somehow this suggested antimatter being a real thing.

Sure enough the particle was soon discovered; perhaps the discoverers were guided by Dirac's work.

But just why would anyone expect this? Could it not be that an equation works in many cases but not all? Was Dirac surprised by the discovery of the positron or would not finding such a particle have been more of a surprise?

Comment: Dirac's 'positron' is a solution to the Dirac equation with negative energy.  There was a positive-energy solution and negative-energy solution with an energy gap between them.  This led Dirac to postulate that the negative energies are all 'filled up' in a sea of negative-energy charges which is why we never see them.  Actual positrons were later discovered in cosmic rays as a particle with same mass as the electron, but negative its charge.

Comment: The view of Dirac's original interpretation, including the 'sea of negative energy charge' is no longer considered the correct description of physics.  It was superseded by QED, though its Lagrangian is derived from Dirac's ideas.  At any rate, lest you think Dirac was always this lucky - Dirac also investigated the possibility of particles with negative probability wavefunctions (!) - but this type of particles was never discovered.

Comment: My opinion is that theorists DO tend to assume that a fundamental equation “works in all cases” within its domain of theoretical validity until experiment shows otherwise. Unless there is an obvious reason for it to fail for some cases, it would be bizarre to have random failures. The fundamental equations of SR, EM, QM, QFT, GR, etc. don’t have “exceptions” (as far as we know) in their range of validity.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, essentially all the equations of for example classical physics are only applicable within a certain span of circumstances where the behavior of the system can be modeled with one set of rules, and other effects can be ignored because they are too small to get worried about.

Then, when those circumstances (for example, ambient temperature) are extended, those other effects begin to grow and they must be taken into account to get accurate answers. So the equation now has to include not just one but two sets of rules to model the main effect and the side effect.

So in this way Newtonian gravity works just fine if the masses and densities of the gravitating objects are not "too big"; for that case, Einstein's rules of general relativity must be used. Similarly, Newtonian mechanics works just fine until the speeds of the objects become "too big" and Einstein's rules of special relativity take over from there.

I think Dirac and his positrons should be covered in a separate question.